# changing css property in Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

below is my html page, which contains a **button**. in my button **input.ui-button { padding: 0.4em 1em; }** style is added to buttons. it is adding it from **jquery-ui.css .** i have to add **in-line** to change **padding values**. but i can't add this as per instruction. please suggest me is there any other way to set these values other than **in-line style.**

```
       <body>
       <input type="button" onclick="javascript:submitForm('reset');" class="ui-button- default ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only" 
       value="Reset">
      </body>
```

Comment: You should have a separate CSS document anyway. Inline CSS is generally a bad idea. When you've got that sorted, you can use the `.css()` method in jQuery.

Comment: Are you using jQuery.js in your code? why are you still using onclick?

Comment: thanks polynomial, i have added it in separate .css file but it is not reflecting until i add it like inline.

Comment: @David Laberge: i am using query.min.js,query-ui.min.js . and what to use for onClick() ? please suggest. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like

```
  <body>
   <input type="button" id="btn" value="Reset">
  </body>
```

In Javascript:

```
$('#btn').button();                 // to apply the default css style of the jQuery UI boutton
$('#btn').css({'margin-left':'20px'}); // to modify the css of the element
$('#btn').click(function(){
   // This function is called when the bouton is clicked
});
```

Comment: Cheers, also please change "boutton" to "button". :)

Answer (score 1):

Just add your own style sheet overriding the `.ui-button` padding definition:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .ui-button {  padding: 0; }
</style>
```